# JSP session and application objects not keeping track

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am beginning JSP and servlets. When I am adding a username by changing the url, all attributes are changing. But when I am removing the change, all the attributes including the session and application attributes are getting changed? Where am I going wrong?

```
<body>
    <%
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        session.setAttribute("sessionUsername", username);
        application.setAttribute("applicationName", username);
        //request, session, application
    %>
<br>
The username is: <%=username %>
<br> 
The username in session is: <%=session.getAttribute("sessionUsername")%>
<br>
The username in application is: <%=application.getAttribute("applicationName") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what change ? can you elaborate it more?

Comment: If I pass a username through the url, it is visible for all the times I call it. However, when I remove the username, shouldn't the session and application variables hold the username?

Comment: yes it should be until you removed it  from session.check what does `username` has in it when you removed it from url ? but how do  you removed it ? elaborate that in your question as well